# Standard Error of Ridge Logistic Regression Coefficient using caret

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret, glmnet

I am using `caret` package in R, to perform Ridge Logistic Regression.
Now I am able to find the coefficients for each variable.

**Question is:** How to know the standard error of coefficient for each variable produce using Ridge logistic regression?

Here is the sample code that I have:-

```
Ridge1 <- train(Group ~., data = train, method = 'glmnet',
               trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
               tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0, 
                                      lambda = lambda),
               family="binomial")
```

Coefficient of Ridge logistic regression

```
coef(Ridge1$finalModel, Ridge1$bestTune$lambda)
```

How to get a result as in logistic regression model (ie: the standard error, wald statistic, p-value.. etc?)

Answer (score 1):

You don't get p-values and confidence intervals from ridge or glmnet regressions because it is very difficult to estimate the distribution of the estimator when a penalization term is present. The first part of [the publication for R package hmi](https://stat.ethz.ch/%7Enicolai/confidence.pdf) touches on this and you can check out post such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224796/why-are-confidence-intervals-and-p-values-not-reported-as-default-for-penalized) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171448/ridge-regression-in-r-with-p-values-and-goodness-of-fit)

We can try something below, for example getting the optimal lambda from caret and using that in another package `hmi` to estimate confidence intervals and p-values, but I would interpret these with caution, they are very different from a custom logistic glm.

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

X = as.matrix(PimaIndiansDiabetes[,-ncol(PimaIndiansDiabetes)])
y = as.numeric(PimaIndiansDiabetes$diabetes)-1

lambda = 10^seq(-5,4,length.out=25)

Ridge1 <- train(x=X,y=factor(y), method = 'glmnet',family="binomial",
               trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
               tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0, 
                                      lambda = lambda))

bestLambda = Ridge1$bestTune$lambda
```

Use hdi, but note that the coefficients will not be exactly the same as what you get with caret, or glmnet:

```
library(hdi)
fit = ridge.proj(X,y,family="binomial",lambda=bestLambda)

cbind(fit$bhat,fit$se,fit$pval)

                  [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
pregnant  0.1137868935 0.0314432291 2.959673e-04
glucose   0.0329008177 0.0035806920 3.987411e-20
pressure -0.0122503030 0.0051224313 1.677961e-02
triceps   0.0009404808 0.0067935741 8.898952e-01
insulin  -0.0012293122 0.0008902878 1.673395e-01
mass      0.0787408742 0.0145166392 5.822097e-08
pedigree  0.9120151630 0.2927090989 1.834633e-03
age       0.0116844697 0.0092017927 2.041546e-01
```